# hive/sql how to check multiple repeats of a column value and aggregate those or display range of columns

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

this is different question than the one i asked before, please read through its different logic

suppose i have a table as below with 6 columns

```
name    orderno productcategory amount  description code
KJFSFKS 1   1   40  D1  x1
KJFSFKS 2   2   50  D2  y1
KJFSFKS 3   2   67  D3  b1
KJFSFKS 4   2   10  D4  a1
KJFSFKS 5   3   2   D5  ws1
KJFSFKS 6   3   5   D6  ks1
KJFSFKS 7   3   6   D7  pw3
KJFSFKS 8   4   8   D8  ju7
KJFSFKS 9   5   8   D9  87y
KJFSFKS 10  5   10  D10 ky9
```

the product category has multiple repeats of values '2','3', and '5'

my logic says, if there are multiple repeats of product column, sum the amount column, chose description corresponding to higher orderno,

**concatenate code column with a '-' for low and high orderno for the same productcategory code** (basically the range)

else
if there are no multiple repeats of productcategory column(values '1' and '4') move all the values straight without any aggregations

so output looks as below

```
name    orderno productcategory amount  description code
KJFSFKS 1   1   40  D1  x1
KJFSFKS 2   2   127 D4  y1-a1
KJFSFKS 5   3   13  D7  ws1-pw3
KJFSFKS 8   4   8   D8  ju7
KJFSFKS 9   5   18  D10 87y-ky9
```

Comment: What about this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/45328004/2700344 ? I have answered, but you have created one more modified question and didn't accept my answer.

Comment: And what have you tryed?

Comment: that other question i have to still test, this is a different scenario

Comment: Well, you see, answering your questions requires some efforts of course and there should be some motivation for answerer. Motivation is a challenge, interesting question and your thanks. Answering slightly modified question without being awarded for the previous one gives too little motivation. What do you think?

Comment: to be frank i liked the different person answer to the previous question, but i would test your solution too, i did not like union statement in the subquery

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hive/SQL bundling columns for few columns,rest of the columns are pull based lowest/highest of other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45328004/hive-sql-bundling-columns-for-few-columns-rest-of-the-columns-are-pull-based-low)

Comment: sorry this is not duplicate, it has another extra logic which makes this totally different, extra column with different logic

Comment: The logic is not completely different, just additional columns, of course you can try to apply  Dudu Markovitz solution with named_struct as well. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    select name, orderno, productcategory, amount, description, 
           case when codelow=codehigh then codelow else concat(codelow,'-',codehigh) end as code
    from
    (
    select name, orderno, productcategory, sum(amount) over(partition by name, productcategory) amount, 
    first_value(description) over(partition by name, productcategory order by orderno desc) description,
    first_value(code) over(partition by name, productcategory order by orderno desc) codehigh,
    first_value(code) over(partition by name, productcategory order by orderno asc) codelow,
    row_number() over (partition by name, productcategory order by orderno) rn
    from your_table
    )s where rn=1;
```

---

```
OK
KJFSFKS 1       1       40      D1      x1
KJFSFKS 2       2       127     D4      y1-a1
KJFSFKS 5       3       13      D7      ws1-pw3
KJFSFKS 8       4       8       D8      ju7
KJFSFKS 9       5       18      D10     87y-ky9
Time taken: 12.638 seconds, Fetched: 5 row(s)
```

Comment: Very nice! Is the s in `)s` there because subqueries require an alias (even if that alias is unused)?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin  Right, the subqueries require an alias